# How does Entity Framework 6 order migrations

Tags: .net, entity-framework-6

What's the order of the migrations that get run when the db context is configured with `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`? The autogenerated migration classes don't seem to contain any ordering. The only place that seems to have a clue about the order is the migration filename / the timestamp - but that doesn't seem likely or available at runtime... right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial migration name *is* actually what is used. This is also the same as the initial file name but you can obviously change that.

In EntityFramework, when you generate a migration, you may be familiar with editing the file to customize the migration.

[image]

```
    public partial class InitialCreate : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            CreateTable(
                "dbo.Blogs",
                c => new
                    {
                        BlogId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                        Name = c.String(),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.BlogId);
            
        }
        
        public override void Down()
        {
            DropTable("dbo.Blogs");
        }
    }
```

But a designer file is also generated and it has a few properties that you **shouldn't** edit:

```
[GeneratedCode("EntityFramework.Migrations", "6.4.4")]
public sealed partial class InitialCreate : IMigrationMetadata
{
    private readonly ResourceManager Resources = new ResourceManager(typeof(InitialCreate));
        
    string IMigrationMetadata.Id
    {
        get { return "202111200213248_InitialCreate"; }
    }
        
    string IMigrationMetadata.Source
    {
        get { return null; }
    }
        
    string IMigrationMetadata.Target
    {
        get { return Resources.GetString("Target"); }
    }
}
```

In the [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/ef6/blob/main/src/EntityFramework/Migrations/Infrastructure/MigrationAssembly.cs#L32) of EF6, you can see the migrations are reflected from your migration assembly:
Every class that inherits from `DbMigration` is used and then ordered by the `Id` property.

```
_migrations
    = (from t in migrationsAssembly.GetAccessibleTypes()
        where t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(DbMigration))
                && typeof(IMigrationMetadata).IsAssignableFrom(t)
                && t.GetPublicConstructor() != null
                && !t.IsAbstract()
                && !t.IsGenericType()
                && t.Namespace == migrationsNamespace
        select (IMigrationMetadata)Activator.CreateInstance(t))
        .Where(mm => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(mm.Id) && mm.Id.IsValidMigrationId())
        .OrderBy(mm => mm.Id)
        .ToList();
```

Even if you rename the files, the `Id` will still have its initial value when you created the migration keeping the migrations in lexical *and* chronological order as EF6 sees it.

It's pretty much the same for EFCore except that it has moved from a property to an attribute on the designer file:

```
    [DbContext(typeof(MyContext))]
    [Migration("20211118001328_InititialCreate")]
    partial class Init {}
```

And [EFCore](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/main/src/EFCore.Relational/Migrations/Internal/MigrationsAssembly.cs#L56) looks for that attribute on classes that inherit from `Migration`.

```
var items
    = from t in Assembly.GetConstructibleTypes()
        where t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Migration))
            && t.GetCustomAttribute<DbContextAttribute>()?.ContextType == _contextType
        let id = t.GetCustomAttribute<MigrationAttribute>()?.Id
        orderby id
        select (id, t);
```